# Xmonad- reload untiled window

Tags: xmonad

Sometimes, for instance, when i have a terminal and firefox open in the same workspace, and then i close the terminal, firefox will not tile properly, that is it won't take up the full screen, it will just remain taking only half the screen.

Is there a way to reload the window to make it tile properly or do i have to close and reopen each time?

Answer (score 0):

You can try pressing <kbd>mod</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> (Usually corresponding to <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>). According to the [man page](http://xmonad.org/manpage.html) it

> Push window back into tiling

That's a good way to refresh the tiling when there is problem with windows.